Why does my car make a squeak/pump sound when I’m giving it gas?
2011 Impreza Outback sport with 4EAT. Changed radiator and spark plug wires then this noise came. Was told it was trans so swapped it with a used trans and it’s still there. Happens in both drive/reverse. Not in neutral or park. Now it seems like it only comes when I give it gas. It seems to drive fine but I just don’t want to mess something up.
https://youtube.com/shorts/0UC3vA7Xnyo?si=644tFmDTJYKFjrBJ
